migrating VPS with no settings changes generate an Passenger error when browser calls a page
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled is generating the following error.  The VPS is a new install and replicates the data from another VPS also running Ubuntu, albeit an older version (20.04 -> 24.04)
2024/12/18 16:47:18 [alert] 82522#82522: *299 Error opening '/home/deploy/app/current/Passengerfile.json' for reading: Permission denied (errno=13); This error means that the Nginx worker process (PID 82522, running as UID 33) does not have permission to access this file. Please read this page to learn how to fix this problem: https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/admin/nginx/troubleshooting/?a=upon-accessing-the-web-app-nginx-reports-a-permission-denied-error;  ; Extra info, client: [...], server: app.2ld.com, request: "GET /config.json HTTP/1.1", host: "app.2ld.com"

This Passengerfile.json does not exist in any application I have dealt with.
The error message is also a bit misleading as it invokes  relaxing permissions to the Nginx worker process on directories I have never encountered before.
Nginx and passenger processes are spun up.  the relevant bit of the sites-enabled file has
  server_name app.2ld.com;
  root /home/deploy/app/current/public;

  passenger_enabled on;
  passenger_app_env production;

  location /cable {
    passenger_app_group_name app_websocket;
    passenger_force_max_concurrent_requests_per_process 0;
  }

What needs to get fixed in this configuration?

chmod o+x $HOME
will allow requests to be served.
rather than deleting the question, leaving it here for eventual use.
